# How to extract text which are outside and inside a bracket from a sentence through javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a sentence stored in a variable.That sentence I need to extract into 3 parts   which I have mentioned in other 3 variable in my code,for now I have hard coded in the variable. Then I need to console those variable separately.I have already tried with slice for first one,is there any better way to do it.Here is the code below.Can anyone please help me.

### HTML

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

### SCRIPT

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 var maintext = "Welcome to project,are you (1. Existing user or 2. new user)"  ;
 var text_split1 = maintext.split(' ').slice(0,4).join(' ');
//var text_split1 =  "Welcome to project,are you" ; /*this text should come from maintext after extraction*/
var text_split2 = "1. Existing user" ; /*this text should come from maintext after extraction*/
var text_split3 = "2. new user" ; /*this text should come from maintext after extraction*/
console.log(text_split1);
console.log(text_split2);
console.log(text_split3);
});
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? What specifically are you having difficulty with?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split

Comment: I have tried slice,but if there any other better way to fix this, var text_split1 = maintext.split(' ').slice(0,4).join(' ');

Comment: You need to explicitly state your rules.  eg text1 is text before first `(`, text2 is inside the bracket, before and no including "or", etc.   Otherwise it's just guesswork and only fit for this exact scenario - which your existing code is also; only fit for this exact scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best option in this case is to create a regular expression.

In your case (if I got it right) you have a sentence consisting of:

1. Some text
2. Open parenthesis '('
3. More text
4. The word 'or'
5. More text
6. Close parenthesis ')'

So you want a regex to match the format above and you want to capture the items 1, 3 and 5.

Here, I made the regex for you: `/^(.*) ?\((.*) or (.*)\)$/`

Now, using the function `exec(string)` you can match the desired string and capture the desired sections from it.

```
regex = /^(.*) ?\((.*) or (.*)\)$/;
maintext = "Welcome to project,are you (1. Existing user or 2. new user)";
matches = regex.exec(maintext);
text_split1 = matches[1];
text_split2 = matches[2];
text_split3 = matches[3];
```

Notice that I didn't use `matches[0]`. That's because this is the full match from the regex, which, in this case, would be the full string you had at first.

Also, notice that the regex may fail with any of the texts inside the parenthesis contain the full word 'or', which is being used to separate the two portions of the string. You must secure this won't happen, or maybe use some special character to separate the two texts instead of the word.

Comment: Thanks for you help

Comment: You could use word-boundary `\bor\b` or whitespace `\sor\s` so that it's not picked up inside a word.  Still won't fix the issue when there's more than one `" or "`.

Comment: @freedomn-m, I used whitespaces.

Comment: `\s` is for whitespace - you've used a space, subtle difference (that likely has no impact on OPs scenario, but just for completeness)

Comment: I need one more help,some times sentence may like this 'Welcome to project,are you (1. Existing user,2. Test user or 2. new user)' ,I need to get all options in separate console. so how to handle in this case

Comment: It all comes to picking a pattern and sticking to it, then creating a regex that fits any case. Just to clarify: these texts are authored by you or by someone else?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you take a look at the [Split](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp), [Substring](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substring.asp) and [IndexOf](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof.asp) methods.

For example if you wanted to grab what's inside the parenthesis you could do

```
var inside_split = maintext.substring(maintext.indexOf( "(" ) + 1, maintext.indexOf( ")" ) )
```

and then whats outside of it

```
var outside_split = maintext.substring(0, maintext.indexOf("(") - 1)
```

or with Split

```
var split_Text = maintext.split("(")
```

Careful with Split here because it'll result in the last parenthesis being included in.

```
Array [ "Welcome to project,are you ", "1. Existing user or 2. new user)" ]
```

and from that you can Split the two options with

```
split_Text[1].split("or")
```

which results in

```
Array [ "1. Existing user ", " 2. new user)" ]
```

and then manipulate the remaining closing parenthesis

Comment: var inside_split = maintext.substring(maintext.indexOf( "(" ) + 1, maintext.indexOf( ")" ) ) , I am fine with this but how to separate both the sentence from 'or'  again

Comment: Did you read the rest of the post? You can pass "or" to Split