# How to extract sentence which are separated from 'comma' and 'or' into different parts of sentence using javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a sentence stored in a variable.That sentence I need to extract into 4 parts which I have put into variables in my code,I can able to extract here and get into console but I am not getting how to extract '1. Existing user 2. Test user' separately .Here is the code below.Can anyone please help me.

```js
   

$(document).ready(function() {
  regex = /.+\(|\d. \w+ user/g;
  maintext = "Welcome to project, are you a hero(1. Existing user, 2. Test user or 3. new user)";
  matches = maintext.match(regex);
  text_split0 = matches[0].slice(0, -1);
  text_split1 = matches[1];
  text_split2 = matches[2];
  text_split3 = matches[3];
  console.log(text_split0);
  console.log(text_split1);
  console.log(text_split2);
  console.log(text_split3);
  $(".messages").append('<li>'+text_split0+'</li><li>'+text_split1+'</li><li>'+text_split2+'</li><li>'+text_split3+'</li>');
  $("li:contains('undefined')").remove()
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <ul class="messages">
```

Comment: Follow on question from: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53397205/how-to-extract-text-which-are-outside-and-inside-a-bracket-from-a-sentence-throu

Comment: You need to define how these are separated. eg is it always "2." or will there be 4./5.?

Comment: How to get another element(comma) in regular expression,I am not getting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  regex = /.+\(|\d. \w+ user/g;
  maintext = "Welcome to project, are you (1. Existing user 2. Test user or 3. new user)";
  matches = maintext.match(regex);

  text_split0 = matches[0].slice(0, -2);
  text_split1 = matches[1];
  text_split2 = matches[2];
  text_split3 = matches[3];
  console.log(text_split0);
  console.log(text_split1);
  console.log(text_split2);
  console.log(text_split3);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I believe (from the existing regex) that matches[1] should be "Welcome to project,are you".  This works nicely as the 2nd of a two-step process though (and might be more appropriate for OP to have this as two steps anyway)

Comment: Thanks for your help,my output should  like this,I need to get  All here -      Welcome to project,are you
1. Existing user
2. Test user
3. new user

Comment: @carreankush oh so add _digit and dot_ to second part of regex `/.+\(|\d. \w+ user/g`

Comment: Can you please modify in code now I am getting output like this in console Welcome to project,are you (
 
1. Existing user
2. Test user

Comment: @carreankush you can trim `(` with `substring`, `substr` or `slice`. I updated the snippet.

Comment: If I change the text in bracket like (1. case1 , cae2 or 3. case3),its showing undefined in console, Here actually my text can be change anytime inside the bracket.It will not fixed